# How do I replace all values in a column with the first value in that columns row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['green', 'red', 'blue'],
                   'B': ['orange', 'nan', 'nan']
                   'C': ['yellow', 'cyan', 'purple']})
```

I want all of column B to equal the 1st row value in column B (orange), without having to type in "orange". How would I go about doing that?

For context, I'm creating many different dataframes, but in one of the columns I only want the single value in the first row of that column, so it's impractical to type it in each time like this:

```
df[['B']] = "orange"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a slightly cleaner way than the above answer might just be to do:

`df['B'] = df['B'][0]`

Comment: ahh...very nice, agreed, much cleaner

Comment: Thank you all who contributed! Feels different when you're not doing it in the tutorials!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it

`df['B'] = [df['B'].iloc[0]] * len(df)`

It takes the first row of column B without having to type it